# Fechar browser automaticamente depois do alerta

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Como eu faço para o browser fechar automaticamente depois do alerta?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>  
<body>
  <div onmouseover="showText();" onmouseout="javascript:alert('my alert');" id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>

function alert(){
  alert("my alert");
}
```

Comment: Fechar o browser todinho? Não é meio violento?

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar:

```
window.close();
```

após o alerta.

Comment: Tem como postar a resposta de modo mais completo? Com a chamada no `onmouseout`?

Comment: explica melhor?

Comment: Então cara, vendo melhor, este método window.close(); só é permitido quando a janela é aberta pelo método window.open(); Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: Mas qual seria o motivo de você querer fechar a aba ou janela? Isso não é uma boa.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer algo assim:

```js
function alerta(){
alert('my msg');
}
function fechar(){
window.close();
}
```

```css
#algo{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div id='algo' onmouseover='alerta()' onmouseout="fechar()"></div>
```